# How to store JSP views in classpath instead of webapp?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to store JSP files in `src/main/resources/templates`
but after setup i get not found error. It seems that `spring.mvc.view.prefix` only supports path for folder in wepabb folder.

> ```
> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> ```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = classpath*:/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

And this is the src file structure:

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───example
│   │           └───demo
│   │                   DemoApplication.java
│   │                   DemoController.java
│   ├───resources
│   │   └───templates
│   │           test.jsp
│   └───webapp
```

Comment: Possibly https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1 will help. JSPs aren't really designed to be served from the classpath, but there are various workarounds, some hairier than others.

Comment: JSP have limitations, one is they only work in a proper webapp in a war file. Serving them from the classpath generally won't work without resorting to hacks. You might be better of using something like thymeleaf or mustache instead.

Comment: @DaveNewton you can add an answer

Comment: @Alex78191 Nah, self-answering is fine--I didn't test the answer, so your verification is a better approach than me answering :)

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1) (from [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414002/how-to-store-jsp-views-in-classpath-instead-of-webapp?noredirect=1#comment110384284_62414002)) is to put jsp file in folder

`src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/templates/` 
and set

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

Folder  `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` works like `src/main/webapp`